# css - can a div overflow its relative overflow:hidden container?

Tags: html, css, overflow

Is it possible to make the whole .menu visible? (keeping overflow of .box hidden and its position relative).

```
<style>
.box {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.menu {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
}
</style>

<div class="box">
    <div class="menu"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   <style>
    .box {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 400px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #CCCCCC;

    }

.menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;


}
</style>

<div class="box">
    <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```